# Connection Failed to remote jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to connect to jupyter notebook running on my remote server.  The code below has been working fine for days to forward the jupyter notebook running on the port on my ubuntu server to my mac.  It stopped today.  Does anyone know what the issue might be?  Also does anyone know how I can just open the port on my ubuntu server so I wouldn't need the code below?

code:

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 username@111.111.11.122
```

Update:

code:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

Message:

```
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
[I 14:11:23.334 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 2 kernels found
[I 14:11:23.343 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /run/user/1000/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 14:11:24.175 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/username
[I 14:11:24.175 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 14:11:24.175 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8889/?token=d111b8540568567c80796a3be5cf53229fe38360b411a4dd
[I 14:11:24.175 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 14:11:24.178 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///run/user/1000/jupyter/nbserver-77790-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8889/?token=d111b8540568567c80796a3be5cf53229fe38360b411a4dd
```

Update:

code:
ssh -L 8888:localhost:8889 username@111.111.11.122

message:

bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8888
Could not request local forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem time to time. You can try restarting your remote jupyter server (the link contains information to kill existing server and start a new one). Or try a different port number. BTW please share the exact error you face with.

[https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg/remote-access-to-ipython-notebooks-via-ssh][1]

Change "ipython" with "jupyter" and make sure jupyter is installed both on remote machine and your machine.

<strike>ipython</strike> notebook --no-browser --port=8889

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.  I tried:  ssh -L 8000:localhost:8889 username@111.111.11.122  followed by jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889 but I'm still unable to connect to the jupyter notebook running on my server remotely.  Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: What is the message you get when you run "jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889"

Comment: I've added an update to my original post with the message I get after I run "jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889".  Thanks for all your help.  Do you have any idea why this happens?  I've seen it occasionally at work to, but it's rare.  One of those gremlins that pops up, you get it to go away and don't remember how.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know what exactly cause this. So, I don't want to give wrong info and make this more complicated.

You are keeping that terminal open right? The one you wrote "jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889". And also, after you run that, what is the command you run to connect this jupyter-server you created? Can you share that with me, too?

Comment: WRT to message you shared, it is like notebook is running. I am not sure but maybe the thing you want is running that command so it keeps running in background ? If so, you can try it with "nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8899 &". This way it runs in background, you can close your terminal, still connect this server. Try it from your local browser and check it. Then let me know about the result.

Comment: I tried the nohup command you suggested, still no luck connecting  in my local browser with "http://localhost:8899".  I had installed chrome and was trying to get selenium working with chromedriver on my ubuntu server, could that have caused any of this?  And yes, I always kept the terminal open that I'd started jupyter notebook in.  Thanks again for all the tips.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but if it is not a problem, try to reinstall chrome and try again. Again, I'm not sure whether you can reach it locally or from other pc is a same logic. Let's try to fix local connection first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192085/discussion-between-thedarkknight-and-user3476463).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have already opened another Jupyter notebook using port 8888 on your local machine. So solution is simply choosing a different port number, e.g. 8890 or else except 8888 in your case.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that I needed to type localhost:8888 in to the browser on my local machine. I had been typing in the port I opened the jupyter notebook server on, on my remote machine so localhost:8889. Example

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

followed by

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 username@111.111.11.122
```

bang head here.